# Apache prevents use of VirtualHost inside user space? Mac OS X

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I am trying to set up a VirtualHost for some web projects I have undergoing. To do this, I have a folder in my User account ~/Projects/ in which I place all of my projects and I want to remain like that. When I tried to create a VirtualHost under ~/Projects/***aproject***/web Apache denies me access.

After some tries, I discovered that if I put the project under other directory than the user space (~/....) the Apache lets me create the VirtualHost that otherwise denies access.

I think this problem has to do with the `UserDir` directive which I think prevents access to every folder in user space but the ones listed in the `UserDir` - in my case it is `UserDir Sites` - but I do not know how to circumvent this and allow Apache to serve custom user space folders. Any ideas?

The directives in httpd.conf that I am trying are this ones:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/myuser/Projects/myproject/web"
ServerName www.myproject.local
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/Users/myuser/Projects/myproject/web">
Options Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I also have set the directive `NameVirtualHost *:80` in httpd.conf.
And created the appropriate directive in /etc/hosts: `127.0.0.1 www.myproject.local`.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to alter the config for your user:

`users/{username).conf`

Then all `AuthConfig` to `AllowOverride`